# Outlook Graph API call from Sap ui5 Application web ide to Connect the outllok calender to Sap ui5 application

Tags: sapui5, azure-ad-graph-api

I  am trying to call graph api so I had followed the procedure mentioned on the site. I had registerd the App in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/portal/register-app
 and got the client id and and then I am trying to make a ajaxs call url 
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXXXbxxxxxxx-bf22-4bdb-bXX-cd32a729a31f&redirect_uri=https://webidetestingXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/index.html&response_type=code&scope=openid+Mail.Read";
this always opens a login page and How can I pass the username and password after the call.

second-I call this url and enter the credentials it shows me an error of Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

Can you please guide me what i am missing or any example in sap ui5 environment to call such graph Api

Answer (score 0):

> > this always opens a login page and How can I pass the username and password after the call.

When directing the user to the /authorize endpoint , microsoft server will show the login page to let user enter the username/password , after that you couldn't pass username/password to that in your own code .If you don't want to show the login page or need to use own login page , it is possible to sign in a user with the username and password flow as noted [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/). But that flow needs writing passwords for identity provider into your custom website , and you should check more at the Constraints & Limitations section .

> > I call this url and enter the credentials it shows me an error of Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems.

Please provide more details of that error , you could find error message in browser address bar like :https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: error link:https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.

Comment: That error message shows redirect url should match the one you registered for the client app , please check that in your app register page.